How to show that Spin(n) is connected.
I want to show that Spin$(n)$ is connected (for $n\geq2$) by the same argument as explained in the quote from the book in this question: link. I tried to justify why it suffices to find a path between -1 and 1 but I got stuck at some point:
First I proved this Lemma:
Lemma 1. Let $G$ be a topological group and $H \subseteq G$ a subgroup. If $G/H$ is connected and $H$ lies entirely in one path-connected component of $G$, then $G$ is connected.
Proof:
Denote by $\pi: G \rightarrow G/H$ the canonical projection. Let $G=U \cup V$ with $U,V$ disjoined and open. Now for any $g \in U$ and $gh_1, gh_2 \in gH$ there is a path $\gamma$ between $h_1$ and $h_2$ and thus also a path between $gh_1$ and $g h_2$ ($t \mapsto g\gamma(t)$). Thus $gh_1, gh_2 \in U$ and more generally $gH \subseteq U$. It follows that $\pi^{-1}(\pi(U))=U$ (because if $\pi(g)\in\pi(U)$ then $\exists u \in U: gH=uH \Rightarrow g \in U$) and analogously  $\pi^{-1}(\pi(V))=V$. In particular $\pi(U)$ and $\pi(V)$ are open and disjoined. Since $G/H$ is connected we must have $U=\emptyset \lor V= \emptyset$.
Now I want to argue that the continuous surjection $\lambda: \text{Spin}(n) \rightarrow \text{SO}(n)$ induces a continuous bijection on the homogenous space:
\begin{align}
    f: \text{Spin}(n)/\{1,-1\} \rightarrow \text{SO}(n)
\end{align}
If I knew that Spin$(n)$ were compact then I'd know that this bijection is a homeomorphism and I could use the Lemma (Knowing that SO$(n)$ is connected).
Is my line of argument correct? If so could someone tell me how I could show that Spin$(n)$ is compact? I know that it is a closed subset of the Clifford group, so maybe I could show that the latter is compact?
